# How can I find sequences of rows based on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

THis is my `dataframe`:

[image: Screenshot of dataframe]

I am trying to find the most common sequences of `length` and `delivery_type` combined per over. ie every six balls. Is there any way of finding how many times each sequence happens?

**edit**: I'd also like to label these patterns and create a column called `ball_sequence`

**edit2**: I have now combined `delivery_type` and `length` in the `length/type` column. eg ESSY is 'Extra Short Slow Yorker'

[image: New DataFrame]

I have also created a small table of expected outcome. The sequence must occur in the same over and cannot be any random sequence of 6:

[image: Expected output:]

Comment: Can you show what the expected output would be in this case?

Comment: @RafG I will make another column that combines 'length and 'delivery_type and then a small table that shows the output I would like. Will let you know when done.

Comment: @RafG please see the edited question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```py
(df.groupby(["Event_name", "Batfast_id", "Session_no", "Overs"])["length/type"]
   .apply(lambda x: ",".join(x))  ## Creates sequences for each over
   .value_counts()                ## Returns counts of sequences
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Unfortunately this just gives a long list of values. I have enclosed output in the question

Comment: I have made some changes. Please check now. It is not entirely clear from the dataframe snippet that you have provided but I am assuming that every over can be uniquely identified using the combination of "Event_name", "Batfast_id", "Session_no" and "Overs" columns from the dataframe.

Comment: That has worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way of providing a condition where it only considers complete overs? Currently it is also considering incomplete overs where only 2 or 3 balls are delivered

Comment: Maybe you could try adding: `.loc[lambda x: x.str.count(",") == 5]` after using the `apply` method

Comment: Is there a way to add the number of the delivery on to the end of each value in the sequence: eg ES_S_ES_1,ES_S_ES_2,ES_S_ES_3,ES_S_ES_4,ES_S_ES_5,ES_S_ES_6. or anything along those lines that numbers each delivery in the sequence?

Comment: It would really help me to do this for grouping deliveries later